# How to make paypal standard payment option visible while checkout in opencart

Tags: php, paypal, opencart, paypal-sandbox

I added the Paypal Standard Payments module to my Opencart store and went through the following:

Extensions>Payments>Paypal Payments Standard>edit> filled up all the details here and enable the sandbox mode as well.

Now, when I checkout from the store, under the 'Payment Method' option, all i see is 'Cash on Delivery' Checkbox. How do i make Paypal Payment option visible or available to the customer?

Answer (score 2):

Two possible reasons :

- You have set amount in `Total` field (The checkout total the order must reach before this payment method becomes active.) and placing and order less than that amount
- You have not set `Status:` dropdown to enabled
- may be because you have set your currency to something like INR which is not supported by paypal

So as you mentioned you set your currency to INR which is not yet supported by paypal.

In practice you can make the Paypal payment to show by adding your currency code to `$currencies` array in `catalog/model/payment/pp_standard`

but if that currency is not supported by Paypal then when arriving at Paypal website for payment that amount will change to USD without any conversion ,so 200 INR becomes 200 USD ( i did my experiment might be wrong though)

List of supported currencies is given here https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_intro-outside

Comment: Did both. Checked again. Still unable to see that option. I am localhost

Comment: I tried changing the currency to USDOllor and that works fine. Any way to add INR to the list?

Comment: I have Enabled the module, €40 in the basket and minimum price to 1 and still see only Cash On Delivery as sole Payment Method. Very frustrated with opencart.